# Way to Validate bean using Spring before Hibernate Validators

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.2.17 Release . I have implemented the compareTo and hashCode methods in the beans. @Valid annotation calls the Hibernate Validator first.

Any javax Validations like @NotNull are being checked for after the hashCode method call. Hashcode has variables which can be null . How can I ensure that the Data validation is done before the HashCode method.